# Passing class type object to WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

While consuming WCF services, WSDL file gives details about class type parameter and its properties accepted by the WCF service. How a web API client would know about the class type parameter and its fields information accepted by the web API method.

Comment: you need to create documentation from your API so that client will know what they need to pass for calling that API. you can use swagger document which will help a client to get know sample request and response

Comment: So these document needs to be passed on to client apart from giving the web API url?

Comment: yes you can pass that document to a client to get understanding about your request and response object of API https://swagger.io/swagger-ui/